# Universal Windows Platform UWP default data stored

Tags: c#, textbox, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I have problem with understand Windows Universal App LifeCycle

I want to know where data from textBox are saved.

Example:
Create new project -> put TextBox into MainPage.xaml. -> run application and fill this textBox -> use suspend ->and when I back to app (resumed method) all data are still in textBox (without write any piece of code).

My question is where this data are stored, when they are saved and from where the application know what data i put into textbox.

Comment: an app suspended is not closed, so the app is retained on memory.

Comment: Yes I know about it, but i want to know exacly where default app state is saved. System somewhere stores/save these data?

Comment: what mean with default app state? you asked about what happens when the app is suspended, in that case nothing is stored, program is still on memory

Comment: So while I will use the suspended application is "frozen" and does not save the state from TextBox? And when I use "onResume" system only restores what was before suspended?

Comment: Do you want store you default data when the application is suspended. An d when the user go back to the application,he can see the data no matter the application be Terminated.

Comment: Icero yes, that's it, until the app isn't killed it will be on memory. If the app is then killed your app will be restarted the next time it's used and no state is restored, is your responsability to store any state you need to be restored in this case as @JaydenGu said.

Answer (score 1):

Your app is Suspended in Memory. There is no writing to disk, as the app has not been **ClosedByUser** or **Terminated**.

Check out [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle) to understand App Lifecyle better.